# power-of (pow) constraints in minizinc

Tags: constraints, minizinc

Is there any way (direct or indirect) by which pow constraints can be supported in minizinc. Gecode supports the [pow constraint](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelFloatArith.html#gad4732e9486013a8955436e693cb80384) with float and int variables, however Minizinc and FlatZinc does not support pow for variables. Minizinc and Flatzinc supports pow only for parameters to the model. 
Any pointers on where to look to add support in MiniZinc to Flatzinc (mzn2fzn) parser to do this.

I want to have a constraint such as - " pow( 4, x ) == y " , i.e. 4^x == y .

Comment: Added a bug before I saw this question: http://www.minizinc.org/trac/ticket/54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know it's not possible in current version of MiniZinc to use pow/2 with decision variables.

Perhaps it would be enough to emulate it with "exists"? Here's a simple example (the domain of "i" is too large in this example).

```
var 0..10000: x;
var 0..10000: y;
solve satisfy;

constraint
      exists(i in lb(x)..ub(x)) (
         i = x /\
         pow(4,i) = y
      )
;

output [ show([x,y]) ];
```

Comment: Do you know of any plans of adding support for pow with decision variables in MiniZinc, given that GECODE already supports it ?

Comment: @user3483760 I don't know of any plans to extend the pow function. The upcoming MiniZinc version 2.0 will have quite a few new features, let's hope that it also include a better working pow.

Comment: It's been confirmed that minizinc will include this, however the support from the actual solvers is apparently lacking somewhat. See [feature request](http://www.minizinc.org/trac/ticket/54#comment:1).